# Kubernetes service is not getting external IP

Tags: kubernetes

I running Kubernetes cluster on premises, initialized using KubeAdm. I configured [flannel](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#flannel) networking plugin.

When I exposing service as a NodePort, I'm not able to receive external IP. What do I miss?

[image]

My deployment yaml looks as the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testapp
  labels:
    run: testapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    run: testapp
---------
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: testapp
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      name: testapp
      labels:
        run: testapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: [omitted]
          name: testapp
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
             livenessProbe:
               httpGet:
               path: /api/health
               port: 80
```

**Environment details:**

Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3", GitCommit:"d2835416544f298c919e2ead3be3d0864b52323b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-07T12:22:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3", GitCommit:"d2835416544f298c919e2ead3be3d0864b52323b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-02-07T11:55:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Running Ubuntu Server 16.04 on vSphere VM (on-prem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not see an "External-IP" value here if you using a node port.

From [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport):

> If you set the type field to "NodePort", the Kubernetes master will allocate a port from a flag-configured range (default: 30000-32767), and **each Node will proxy that port** (the same port number on every Node) into your Service. That port will be reported in your Service’s spec.ports[*].nodePort field.

So, you don't have a one IP which can be shown there.  You can connect to any of your nodes to defined NodePort.

Comment: According to documentation: "The IP address in the EXTERNAL-IP column is the one that is available on the public internet. The CLUSTER-IP is only available inside your cluster/private cloud network."    ... "For some parts of your applications you may want to expose a Service onto an external IP address. Kubernetes supports two ways of doing this: NodePorts and LoadBalancers."  Taken from: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service#exposing-the-service

Comment: And so? External-IP you will see when you using a LoadBalancer mode, not a NodePort. In NodePort you have no dedicated external IP for you service, all your nodes will handle the connection to your service.

Answer (score 17):

You would not get an external IP when exposing service as a nodeport. Exposing Service on a Nodeport means that your service would be available on externally via the NodeIP of any node in the cluster at a random port between 30000-32767(default behaviour) .

In your case , the port on which your service is exposed is port 31727.

Each of the nodes in the cluster proxy that port (the same port number on every Node) into the pod where your service is launched.

Easiest way to see this using

```
kubectl describe service <service-name>
```

Check for detail of the Nodeport in the result above.

Later get any the node Ip of any of the nodes in the cluster using

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

You can now access your service externally using `<Node-IP>:<Node-Port>`

Additionally, if you want a fixed Node port, you can specify that in the yaml.

PS: Just make sure you add a security rule on your nodes to allow traffic on the particular port.

Comment: What happens if we use <Pod-IP>:<Node-Port> ?

Answer (score 1):

In NodePort you won't get an external IP ,
Try to use type:LoadBalancer instead of NodePort to get external IP that's what you actually want ,

apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:

name: my-service

spec:

selector:

```
app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
```

ports:

```
- protocol: TCP

  port: 80

  targetPort: 9376
```

clusterIP: 10.0.171.239

type: LoadBalancer

status:

loadBalancer:

```
ingress:

- ip: 192.0.2.127
```